# Finding derivative using matlab

Tags: matlab

Suppose I can generate infinitely many values of x and f(x). The functional form of f(x) is now known. Now I need the value of f'(x) at each point. What is the best way to find it with satisfactory accuracy using matlab. In short it is described below

```
x:    1     1.1    1.2..............................
f(x): 2      4      5...............................
f'(x):?      ?      ?...............................
```

Comment: "Suppose I can generate infinitely many values of x and f(x)" But... you can't...

Comment: You may consider the following approximation :

$$ f'(x) = \frac{-f(x+2h)+8f(x+h)-8f(x-h)+f(x-2h)}{12h} + O(h^4) $$

Answer (score 1):

Using finite many points, you can use the finite difference formula
$$\frac{f(x+h) - f(x-k)}{h+k}$$
to approximate the derivative $f'(x)$ at $x$. For example, to evaluate $f'(1.1)$, you can take $h = 0.1 = k$. Then
$$f'(1.1) = \frac{f(1.2) - f(1.0)}{0.2} = 5\times(5-2) = 15$$
The accuracy is improved if the partition is finer, i.e. $h$ an $k$ are chosen smaller. But that requires more points.

There are more finite difference formulas. You can goggle for more.

Comment: What about the first and last point

Comment: You can take $h = 0$ and $k = 0.1$ for the last point. This is the backward difference formula.